# Can you find my name?

Tags: riddle

> I am known for my sacredness,
>
> I also provide brightness.
>
> I am very noble.
>
> I have a million inside me,
>
> But I end with a thousand.

***Who am I?***

**HINT 1**

> Members of PSE know me!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***OK***, soo... Thanks, but is it:

> [Omega Krypton](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/51131/omega-krypton)?

```
I am known for my sacredness,
```

> ?[Om](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Om), as revealed by OP in comments

```
I also provide brightness.
```

> Krypton is a noble gas, shedding light

```
I am very noble.
```

> Noble gas...

```
I have a million inside me,
```

> Hidden in Omega is [Mega](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mega-), meaning 1000000

```
But I end with a thousand.
```

> ton (should be tonne) = 1000 kg?

Comment: **Om** for Sacredness